# Выполнение Action-а без редиректов

Tags: asp.net, c#, asp.net-mvc

Как выполнить `Action` без редиректов и перегрузок страниц?

По нажатии на кнопку надо добавить товар в корзину и оставить пользователя на той же странице.

Пробовал метод с `void`, перенаправляет на `locachost/home/Add`

```
public void Add( Product model )  
{
    var service = new BasketService();
    if ( ModelState.IsValid )
    {
        service.addProduct(product);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы про ajax что-нибудь слышали?

Comment: Упаковываете ваши данные в JSON и через AJAX отправляете на сервер.

Comment: Спасибо, буду гуглить в эту сторону )